# Add IdentityUser as property of other model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I´m playing around with ASP.NET Identity, using MVC5 and EntityFramework 6.1.3.
**My problem is that I cannot add an IdentityUser as a property to another model.**

My application lets a user create a Project:

```
 public class Project
    {
        public int ProjectID { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
    }
```

In the action method for creating a new project, I'm trying to add the signed in user like this:

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ProjectID,ProjectName")] Project project)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // I added the first two lines of code below. 
                var loggedInUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
                project.ApplicationUser = loggedInUser;
                db.Projects.Add(project);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(project);
        }
```

loggedInUser is set correct, it gets all the right properties. However, when I try to save the updated context, I get the following error:

```
"Validation failed for one or more entities. The validation errors are: User name hellogoodnight@gmail.com is already taken."
```

So, for some reason my code apparently tries to create a new user, instead of adding the existing one to the created Project. Why?
Is this not the way to add an IdentityUser as a navigation property to a model?

Comment: Two general comments, why can't you just store the userid as a property of the class and perform an identity user lookup as needed. Seems more resource efficient. Why can't you also have the class inherit from the identity user model? I think in general your problem is it thinks in the process of saving your new model change, it's trying to save a duplicate just as the error says. You need to work around there only being one entity of any identity user and referencing it rather than trying to resave duplicate data. That is exactly what identity means, one and only one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you have `two` tables with an **one to many** `relationship`.

`Project` entity can have only one `user` attached and `user` entity can have one or many `projects`.

Thus, you need to attach the foreign key in your `Project` class in order to allow `Entity framework` to `map` relationships correctly and establish
associations between `relational` model ( database ) and `conceptual` model.

```
 public class Project
 {
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int ApplicationUserId{ get; set;}
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
 }
```